# How to print properties of stdClass object in PHP?

Tags: php, stdclass

I have an array that contains standard class object. How can I return the properties (print them out) in a stdClass object?

Comment: If you mean just displaying them for debugging or something, print_r or var_dump would both work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you should be able to see them using `var_dump($myObject);`

Answer (score 18):

If you just want to print you can use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var-dump) or [`print_r()`](http://www.php.net/print-r).

```
var_dump($obj);
print_r($obj);
```

If you want an array of all properties and their values use [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/get-object-vars).

```
$properties = get_object_vars($obj);
print_r($properties);
```

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this problem in this way:

```
echo $arrayName[0]->varname;
```

As it is an array of objects, we use -> to access objects attributes/methods.